# Tracking browser metrics inside desktop application

Tags: google-analytics

Our desktop application includes a pane which pulls content from a web page upon loading (think: links to what's new, top support topics, etc.). We have the analytics.js on that page.

We're getting demographic information back like country, which I assume is location-based. We also see language information. When using an embedded web page like this, where is Goolge Analytics getting the language information from? There isn't a way for customers to change language settings for the web part inside our application. We're trying to understand if the language information we're seeing is accurate or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The language report is showing the default language set by a visitor on his/her web browser from which they are accessing your application.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This is a desktop application with an embedded Qt web viewer.